# Delegate Error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to send a `double` value from a `UIView` (which is loaded from a XIB) to a `ViewController` using a delegate

Here is my protocol, it is just sending a double to the main ViewController on a button click.

```
protocol HoursWorkedDelegate{
    func sendHoursWorked(hoursWorked: Double);
}

class HoursWorkedView: UIView{

    var delegate: HoursWorkedDelegate?;

    @IBAction func calculateHoursWorked(sender: AnyObject){

        // Do some calculations for the hoursWorked value


        // Give value 
        delegate!.sendHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
    }

}



// This class now wants that Double value
class ViewController: UIViewController, HoursWorkedDelegate{


    // Conform to protocol
    func sendHoursWorked(hoursWorked: Double){

        // Lets say we just want to assign this value to a textField
        hoursWorkedTextField.text = NSString(format: "%.4f", hoursWorked);
    }

}
```

The error message I get is `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code = EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`

Any help would be much appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: Try `delegate?.sendHoursWorked(hoursWorked)` and see if it still crashes.  I don't see where you're setting your delegate.

Comment: How do I set the delegate? I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a start, change the exclamation point in this snippet to a question mark:

```
delegate!.sendHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
```

This is what's likely causing the crash, as you are force-unwrapping the optional delegate property.  A question mark means we'll only call `sendHoursWorked()` on the delegate if the delegate exists.

That fix will now probably mean that your program is no longer crashing, but you still don't get the desired results, because `sendHoursWorked()` is never called.  We have to tell our `HoursWorkedView` object who is delegating it.

Somewhere in your code, you might have something like this:

```
let hoursWorkedView = HoursWorkedView()

self.view.addSubview(hoursWorkedView)
```

It's right here where we should be setting the delegate:

```
let hoursWorkedView = HoursWorkedView()
hoursWorkedView.delegate = self
self.view.addSubview(hoursWorkedView)
```

Though if it's me, I probably add a constructor to `HoursWorkedView` that accepts the delegate property:

```
init(delegate: HoursWorkedDelegate) {
    super.init()
    self.delegate = delegate
}
```

And now we can just do this:

```
let hoursWorkedView = HoursWorkedView(delegate: self)
self.view.addSubview(hoursWorkedView)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting your view and your viewcontroller mixed up: a ViewController controls things; a view just displays them. The viewController tells the view what to display.

So, you want to connect your button to the viewController -- not the view.  And you don't need a custom view class or a delegate.

Set it up like this:

- create a textField and a button
- create an outlet for the textField
- put calculateHoursWorked directly in your viewController
- create an action to connect the button to calculateHoursWorked
- in calculateHoursWorked, set self.textField.text to the result of the calculation (where "textField" is whatever you named your outlet)

You wouldn't use a delegate in this context because the viewController knows everything the view does. The delegate pattern is for cases where one object has no visibility into another.

EDIT:

That being said, the bug here is that the delegate isn't actually being set anywhere.

Swift Optionals (the ! and ?) help prevent cases like this.  If you explicitly unwrap an optional using !, you have to make sure it's always defined.  In this case, since delegate is defined as optional (?) you have to check it:

```
@IBAction func calculateHoursWorked(sender: AnyObject){

    // Do some calculations for the hoursWorked value


    // Give value 
    if let currentDelegate = self.delegate {
        currentDelegate.sendHoursWorked(hoursWorked)
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if this sub view with a button is used across multiple scenes in his app? Is he to duplicate all this code every time rather than just making this class and instant intent it? What if you had to hook UIAlertView's buttons up to each and every view controller that presented it? Having an alert view delegate is way better...

Comment: The OP's use case appears to be very simple -- the answer is meant to be instructive.  This case doesn't require a custom view subclass at all.  Using a delegate here is overkill, and makes the code flow more difficult to follow.  Keep it simple unless there's a reason to make it more complicated!

Comment: What an assumption given OP didn't post complete code.

Comment: Also, using "@IBAction" implies hooking this up via interface builder. In Interface Builder, it's much, much clearer to put all your action methods in the view controller.

Comment: You are making an assumption still. His view could be loaded from a xib. I have done this exactly hundreds of times.

Comment: Yes, I should have stated, it is loaded from a XIB.